# Data Manipulation in multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to make a function, which takes input as dataframe, and dictionary`{"Col_2":% change,"Col_3":% change}` and it should make the changes to the dataframe.

I Have data frame like this

| Date | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 90 | 100 | 300 |
| 01/02/2022 | 80 | 110 | 310 |
| 01/03/2022 | 92 | 120 | 400 |
| 01/04/2022 | 96 | 130 | 300 |
| 01/05/2022 | 99 | 150 | 500 |
| 01/06/2022 | 105 | 155 | 600 |

Now I pass the dictionary  say,

`{"col_2":-10,"col_3":10}`

Then my desired out would look like this

| Date | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 90 | 90 | 330 |
| 01/02/2022 | 80 | 99 | 341 |
| 01/03/2022 | 92 | 108 | 440 |
| 01/04/2022 | 96 | 113 | 330 |
| 01/05/2022 | 99 | 135 | 550 |
| 01/06/2022 | 105 | 139.5 | 660 |

I followed this code(but didn't get my desired result)

```
def per_change(df,col,per):
    m = 1+per/100
    df['col_2'] *= m
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Series of the dictionary with [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html). By default the missing columns will be NaN, and you fill in the original data with [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

The advantage of this solution is that you do not need to care about the existing columns, if will only multiply the ones present in the dictionary.

Numeric/string columns only:

```
(df+df.mul(pd.Series(d)/100)).combine_first(df)
```

Or to handle dataframes with non-numeric types:

```
(df+df.select_dtypes(include='number').mul(pd.Series(d)/100)).combine_first(df)
```

output:

```
         Date  col_1  col_2  col_3
0  01/01/2022   90.0   90.0  330.0
1  01/02/2022   80.0   99.0  341.0
2  01/03/2022   92.0  108.0  440.0
3  01/04/2022   96.0  117.0  330.0
4  01/05/2022   99.0  135.0  550.0
5  01/06/2022  105.0  139.5  660.0
```

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2022', '01/02/2022', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022'], 'col_1': [90, 80, 92, 96, 99, 105],
                   'col_2': [100, 110, 120, 130, 150, 155],
                   'col_3': [300, 310, 400, 300, 500, 600]})

d = {"col_2":-10,"col_3":10}
```

Comment: is "d" my dictionary here?

Comment: @Amit Yes, sorry I'll clarify

Comment: it is giving me an error"
"unsupported operand type(s)" for + 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: One issue I got here. My dataframe columns ​has been sorted in alphabetical order how to fix this issue?

Comment: You can get the original order by adding `[df.columns]` at the end of the command

Answer (score 1):

You can specify columns names for processing in list and first divide values by `100`, multiple by `Series` from dictionary and add to original `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
def per_change(df,cols,d):
    df[cols] = df[cols].add(df[cols].div(100).mul(pd.Series(d)), fill_value=0)
    return df

d =  {"col_2":-10,"col_3":10}
print (per_change(df,['col_1','col_2','col_3'],d))
         Date  col_1  col_2  col_3
0  01/01/2022   90.0   90.0  330.0
1  01/02/2022   80.0   99.0  341.0
2  01/03/2022   92.0  108.0  440.0
3  01/04/2022   96.0  117.0  330.0
4  01/05/2022   99.0  135.0  550.0
5  01/06/2022  105.0  139.5  660.0
```

Comment: Can you help me in wrapping into this a function?

Comment: One issue I got here. My dataframe columns ​has been sorted in alphabetical order 
how to fix this issue @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Function:

```
def changer(df, change_dic):
   new_df=df.copy()
   for col in change_dic.keys():
      new_df[col] += change_dic[col]*new_df[col]
   return new_df
```

and your edited version:

```
def per_change(df,col,per):
   m = 1+per/100
   df[col] *= m
   return df
```

Comment: I have categorical column say col_3. Then, how I can update the existing dataframe based upon the input dictionary(which includes col_3 as 1 or 0)

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Say me what is the preferred output.